# How to select elements where descendants have special attribute

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I stuck in writing a Linq to XML select and hope that you can help me.

My XML looks like the following:

```
<myXML>
    <parent>
        <child name="ID">0</child>
        <child name="Name">Test 1</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child name="ID">1</child>
        <child name="Name">Test 2</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child name="ID">0</child>
        <child name="Name">Test 3</child>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <child name="ID">2</child>
        <child name="Name">Test 4</child>
    </parent>
</myXML>
```

I try to select all parent elements with a child in it that has attribute ID = 0, so that i get back the following:

```
<parent>
    <child name="ID">0</child>
    <child name="Name">Test 1</child>
</parent>
<parent>
    <child name="ID">0</child>
    <child name="Name">Test 3</child>
</parent>
```

The XML is very big and so the select should be performant. Thanks for your help!!!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query =
    from p in xd.Root.Elements("parent")
    where p
        .Elements("child")
        .Any(c =>
            c.Attribute("name").Value == "ID"
            && c.Value == "0")
    select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

After Loading / Parsing the document into an `XDocument`, for performance, I would use `XPath`, as follows

```
var elements = document
   .XPathSelectElements("/myXML/parent[normalize-space(child[@name='ID'])='0']");
```

i.e. "Find all `parent` elements with `child` elements with an attribute name `ID` and a trimmed value of 0"